# how not to allow a negative number to be entered in for

Tags: java, for-loop

I have tried Math.abs and if statement and nothing works. I am a bit confused. How can I not accept negative numbers with for loop in Java , the user can not enter negative numbers as defense programming? Take the following piece of code :

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

    System.out.print("Νο. " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    arr[i] = input.nextDouble();

}
```

Comment: read the input in a variable, add a while loop that re-reads input while input < 0

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13078995/133203), just remove the part where it checks whether the input is greater than 100.

Comment: Yes but if I say, say while (i <0) while I have already set i = 0; then the result will  always be 'false' right ? , if of course I understood what you mean.

Comment: do you think that 0 is smaller than  0?

Comment: But this way with while I will not be able to do it with a array and so I will not be able to get the user to enter as much information as he wants.

Comment: of course you will be able to do it with an array. and of course you will be able to let the user enter as much as he wants. I didn't suggest you replace the for with a while, I said you should nest a while in your for loop

Comment: Do you want to either 1) ignore negative numbers 2) ensure  that you get at least `array.length`  numbers > 0. or 3) convert  negative to positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the reading of the value in a loop.  Do not exit the loop until the the user enters a non-negative value.  For example..

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  while (true) {
    System.out.print("Νο. " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    arr[i] = input.nextDouble();
    if (arr[i] >= 0) {
      break;
    }
    System.out.println("Value cannot be negative");
  }
}
```

Comment: why while true? all that needs to be in the while is the input.nextDouble(); store that in a variable: while (input < 0 ) 'll work just fine

Comment: @Stultuske I elected to avoid a temporary variable in my example. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are pretty new to Java. Welcome to Java's magical world :)

Depending on what your code looks like, a more "professional" way is to throw an exception:  You may Google a little bit and try to customize your code and how it will react to the exception.

On the other hand, it seems like a simple project, so something like

```
            Double a  = input.nextDouble();
            if(a > 0){
                System.out.println("No negative values allowed");
            }else{
                arr[i] = a;
            }
```

could be enough

Comment: Yes I am new to Java and I really admire the language. I would like to ask, can we do the same when we do not have a array?

Comment: Of course you can

Comment: ` while (true) {
            double a = input.nextDouble();
            if (a > 0) {
                break;
            }else
                System.out.println("no negative values allowed");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("give the value : ");

        while (true) {

            double b = input.nextDouble();

            if (b>0) {
                break;
            }else
                System.out.println("no negative values allowed");
        } `

Comment: my code , i cant do the same because i use double a = input.nextDouble(); inside in the while loop and i cant use it outside of it when i want to calculate something else

Comment: sry for my code in comments i try to learn how to fix it